# should I consider 2 different patch versions of some software as 2 different projects or just one project

Tags: jira

In Software Project Management, [Software versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) uses a convention like this

[image]

For example, skype 6.26.2 and skype 6.26.1 are different versions of the same App.

“Project” is the highest level container in Jira.

when project skype 6.26.1 is delivered, Should I create a new "Project" in Jira, to manage the development of skype 6.26.2?

Comment: Why not use the "target release" field?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Because it seems like a project will never be finished until some product is closed forever.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Thanks for you comments. What is you best practice? Put "6.26.1" and "6.26.2" in the same project? How about "6.25" and "6.26"?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Here is a [related one](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/29699/40663)

Answer (score 2):

In Jira, I've found that a Project best maps to a software product. This enables more efficient use of the Releases and Components functionality. By using the Fix Version field on issues, you can target work toward a particular Release and then use the Releases view to track progress. Internally, to your organization, you may treat a release as a project, but the use of the Fix Version field, along with labels and issue linking, is what you would use for monitoring scope and tracking progress.

By using a single Jira project, you also enable the use of Releases to track Affected Versions. Often used for bugs, this lets you track which released versions a bug is found in. If you split the work up across multiple Jira projects, this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thank you. Does "to track Affected Versions" mean this situation, some bug found in skype 6.26.0 and fixed in skype 6.26.2, so "Affected Versions" are 6.26.0, 6.26.1?

Comment: @JJJohn As long as it existed in 6.26.1, then yes. In most cases, I suspect it would be correct. I can see a few cases, such as if 6.26.1 disabled the feature and 6.26.2 reenabled the feature with the fixed bug, where it may get odd.

Comment: Thank you. A bug is found in 6.26.0, then disable the feature in 6.26.1, and then reenable the feature with fix in 6.26.2. Is this a common and acceptable way to deal with bugs?

Comment: Yes，that's very common in case of a bug is found but you can't fix it quick enough in coming release, Then the best way to handling it is have it  disabled first to stop bleeding

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the "patch" number normally means exactly that ... the latest set of "bug fixes" and maybe "trivial enhancements."  Therefore, I would treat these as a new major milestone of the existing project.  "Minor" releases might be treated the same way.

However, in all cases it's very important to consider what *your* teams actually mean by these numbers.