# Should I put UI, product definition and development in one Jira project?

Tags: jira

Assume I am planning to develop an App like Skype, Product manager needs to define a group of functionalities, UI/UX needs to design the appearance, iOS engineer needs to deliver an iOS app, backend engineer needs to deliver an server.

Should I put all the work about in one Jira project?

Comment: If it’s one product, it should be in one project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [should I consider 2 different patch versions of some software as 2 different projects or just one project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/29693/should-i-consider-2-different-patch-versions-of-some-software-as-2-different-pro)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I'm on the fence as to whether or not that counts as a dup. Certainly, the two Questions have the same answer, but I don't think that necessarily means they're the same question.

Comment: @Sarov, I agree that it is not an obvious duplicate, but for me the decision fell to the other side of the fence. No harm done if the community disagrees with me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, [the advice I gave in a previous question holds](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/29695/30) - one software product is represented by one Jira project. In the simplest case, the definition would be the product manager defining changes by writing some of the tickets in Jira, the UX designer linking tickets to aspects of the mockup, refinement with the entire team, and the use of the Jira Components field to identify iOS vs API work.

However, I can see cases where you may want to isolate the product into a Jira project. Often, this can be more useful where you have a complex product or a portfolio of products that need to be aligned. The output of the product management organization could be things like specific changes for multiple products in the portfolio, design guidelines, component libraries. In these cases, the software product would be different than the product management product and services.

At this level, the biggest factor is your organization. Consider the size of the different departments involved, the existence of product lines or product families or product portfolios, and the products or services offered by each team to other parts of the organization.