# should I consider 2 different major versions of an application as 2 different projects or just one project

Tags: jira

Assume my team is developing an App like Skype. We just delivered 5.0.0 and are planning to develop version 6.

Should I create a new "Project" in Jira, to manage the development of version 6?

One of my concerns is, if I put from skype 5.0.1 to skype 6.26.1, all versions in one project, it seems like the project will never be finished until the product is closed forever.

Comment: This question is, fundamentally, no different than your previous question about patch versions.

Answer (score 0):

It ***absolutely*** **depends** on what that "major version" actually *is,* when compared to the previous one.

Sometimes, a "major version" adds new features to the system but does not make major changes to the existing software (and hardware?) infrastructure, while at other times *the exact opposite* is true.

Therefore, I would turn to your team as the Subject-Matter Experts (SMEs) here:  how do *they* regard the nature of the new version with respect to the existing one?  Are they planning to do *rewrites?*  How much of the existing code-base must they now "touch?"

Perhaps you could briefly present the two alternatives to them, explain the different ways that each might be regarded by themselves and by management, and *ask them* which option they think would better reflect the task at hand?  Because, they're the ones who know best, and it would make a *big* difference in your reporting ... and, the validity of those reports ... if you "guessed wrong" and were, well, "guessing."  Ask the SMEs: the team itself.